# Sql Server : Using CASE with three conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to use `CASE` with three conditions. It is showing error.

**My query :**

```
 select distinct a.phone, other,starttime,duration,imeinumber,
 imsinumber,call_type,a.provider_key, a.celltowerid, siteaddress,
 lat, long, azimuth from cdat a
 left join cdatdupl.dbo.cdatcelltowerareanew b on 
    case 
    when a.provider_key!='9' then a.tower_key=b.tower_key 
    else a.celltowerid = b.celltowerid
        and a.provider_key=b.provider_key 
        and a.state_key end=b.state_key
```

Comment: Close your `CASE` statement with `END`. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Comment: Please **STOP SHOUTING** at us! Don't write in ALL UPPER CASE - it's hard to read, and it's considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, which is just plain rude and offensive. Fix your post and write in normal mixed upper and lower case like every sane person would

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the `CASE` expression with `end` keyword

**syntax**

```
CASE { simple_case_expression
     | searched_case_expression
     }
     [ else_clause ]
     END
```

**Updated Query**

```
 select distinct a.phone, other,starttime,duration,imeinumber,
 imsinumber,call_type,a.provider_key, a.celltowerid, siteaddress,
 lat, long, azimuth from cdat a
 left join cdatdupl.dbo.cdatcelltowerareanew b on 
    case 
        when a.provider_key!='9' then a.tower_key=b.tower_key 
        else (a.celltowerid = b.celltowerid
            and a.provider_key=b.provider_key 
            and a.state_key end=b.state_key)
    end
```